# How to prevent a line break within a line when pagebreak in tcpdf library?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**I am generating a pdf using tcpdf when pagebreak in pdf my line break in two part.How to prevent it please help me out!**
*As u see in image Notes header part break in two parts* 
[image: Pdf image]

**My Code**

```
if($customer_notes !="")
        {
            $pdf->Ln(8);
            $y=$pdf->GetY();
            $pdf->SetFillColor(243,117,37);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'b', 11);
            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(172, '', '', $y, 'Notes', 0, 1, 1, true, 'L', true);

            $pdf->Ln(9);
            $y=$pdf->GetY();
            $pdf->SetTextColor(46,46,46);
            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 11);
            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(172, '', '', $y-3, "<pre>".$customer_notes."</pre>", 0, 1, 0, true, 'L', false);
        }
```

Comment: add $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0); after $pdf->AddPage(); hope this helps.

Comment: this give me only single page,this is not my solution i want full line in next page

Comment: Are you supplying it with html or not?

Comment: I edit my question plz check